# D3js Performance issue

Tags: d3.js

I'm writing a process manager that will show the status of a number of processes running simultaneity.
I'm using the d3js to draw the bar graph so it will do like this:
[Build Process](http://www.incredibuild.com/webhelp/images/monitor%20progress.gif).

For now I have creates this site:
[My Build Process](http://www.webmarkgroup.com/projects/overflow/buildManager)
The behavior of this is like I need(before adding the zoom and making it look batter.
As you can see I have 2 services:

1. Getting the current status of the build(this is drawing all the bars at the start).
2. Getting only the active services(when getting this I'm increasing all the bars together).

The problem is when I look at chrome cpu usage I get more then 20% sometimes.
I this is it because I use d3js. I was able to get the CPU also over 20% when using this  example bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841 just by clicking the screen.

What I do in my code is every couple of seconds I add more pixels to every rect on the screen, everything in dynamic, I'm not drawing everything at once.
After I'm finish with one rect I'm replacing it place in the memory with the next rect in the same line(I have an array that contains all the lines).
All the code is in one loop until the process is done.
My javascript code: www.webmarkgroup.com/projects/overflow/includes/js/buildManager.js
You can see the main code in the "setBars" function in the JS file
I I can't think how to use transition maybe it will be faster, or maybe loading every time all the rect from the DB. what do you think?

Thank you

Comment: The example:http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841

Comment: My JS file: http://www.webmarkgroup.com/projects/overflow/includes/js/buildManager.js

Comment: D3 in itself is not cpu-intensive, but many things you can do with it are.  Any time you are animating things, it will put a burden on the CPU -- even if you're just using CSS transitions.  If you're doing complex calculations for each animation frame (like in the force layout example you linked to) the usage will be even higher.  However, you could definitely optimize your code; it's currently giving a lot of errors, for one thing (rectangles with negative width/height).  For another, you could be using d3 transitions to make your bars grow instead of doing it yourself with setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the the performance tab in the chrome console, and do some recordings while your code is executing. This will let you see exactly what all is taking up your cpu cycles. I suspect that you could be running into Layout thrashing issues. Take a look at using packages like [fastdom](https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom) that would help alleviate some of the issues you might be experiencing.